# Exporting perl script to windows

Tags: perl

I have dozens of perl script on linux server, and I want use some of the script on my desktop. I have active perl installed on my system.

My question is since windows does not have native ssh how I can use the script? My script is use to login to cisco devices via ssh.

Any suggestions or ideas? Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I, for one, love [Cygwin](http://www.cygwin.com/) whenever I would like to pretend that my Windows box is actually a Linux box. Which is most of the time. In particular, I would rather install Cygwin's `openssl` package rather than try to build and/or configure libssh2 on Windows. There are a lot of things I would rather do than build and configure libssh2 on Windows.

I also find that there is less work to do in porting a Perl script from Linux to run on Cygwin than to run on Windows (though what work there is to do is less well documented).

Answer (score 4):

I've successfully used [Net::SSH2](http://cpan.uwinnipeg.ca/module/Net%3a%3aSSH2) in the past.

Comment: It is included into Strawberry Perl.

Comment: I have installed Strawberry Perl and my issue resolved. thanks for the help!

Answer (score 2):

The documentation for [Net::SSH::W32Perl](http://search.cpan.org/perldoc?Net%3a%3aSSH%3a%3aW32Perl) says:

> This module provides limited Net::SSH::Perl functionality under
>   MSWin32 (ActivePerl). See [Net::SSH::Perl](http://search.cpan.org/perldoc?Net%3a%3aSSH%3a%3aPerl) for a functional description.

Comment: thanks for response but this is the message I got when I try to download "Net-SSH-W32Perl is unavailable in PPM, because there aren't any builds for it in the package repositories."

Comment: @DanielEstifanos It does find Net::SSH though, which does imply that it can be used with ActivePerl.

Comment: yes,Net::ssh available but there is no option for password. I need the script to have interactive password option. not sure what to do with that if i use this module.

Comment: @DanielEstifanos There *is* a FAQ that covers that exact topic in the documentation for Net::SSH.

Comment: thanks, I have used ssh expect on active perl. that's solve my issue.

Comment: @DanielEstifanos Is that why you accepted an answer that advises you to use Strawberry perl...?

Comment: Net::SSH::Perl (and Net::SSH::W32Perl) is unmaintained and has lots of bugs. Net::SSH2 is a better option.

Answer (score 1):

You might also want to consider using [Strawberry Perl](http://strawberryperl.com/)

Aside from that, you should be able to run your scripts in the Windows command line using:

```
perl scriptname.pl
```

You can also associate the .pl file extension with Perl and double click on them to start them in the command window. I assume that ActivePerl does this by default. I know that Strawberry Perl does.

Comment: The question is not how to use perl in windows. It is how to use SSH with perl in windows.